# How to Compare Sentences with an idea of the positions of keywords?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to compare the two sentences. As a example,
sentence1="football is good,cricket is bad"
sentence2="cricket is good,football is bad"

Generally these senteces have no relationship that means they are different meaning. But when I compare with python nltk tools it will give 100% similarity. How can I fix this Issue? I need Help.

Comment: Can you provide information on what tool are you using to compare in nltk. if you take 1-gram and do cosine similarity it will be 100 percent match, if you do bi it will decrease a bit and if you do tri-gram it will be all different.

Comment: I'm using wup_similarity and synsets to compare.. Thank you for reply.Any Suggestion code please

Answer (score 1):

Yes `wup_similarity` internally uses synsets for single tokens to calculate similarity

`Wu-Palmer Similarity: Return a score denoting how similar two word senses are, based on the depth of the two senses in the taxonomy and that of their Least Common Subsumer (most specific ancestor node).`

Since ancestor nodes for `cricket` and `football` would be same. `wup_similarity` will return `1`.

If you want to fix this issue using `wup_similarity` is not a good choice.
Simplest token based way would be fitting a `vectorizer` and then calculating similarity.
Eg.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

corpus = ["football is good,cricket is bad", "cricket is good,football is bad"]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3))
vectorizer.fit(corpus)

x1 = vectorizer.transform(["football is good,cricket is bad"])
x2 = vectorizer.transform(["cricket is good,football is bad"])

cosine_similarity(x1, x2)
```

There are more intelligent methods to meaure semantic similarity though. One of them which can be tried easily is Google's USE Encoder.
See this [link](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1)

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a lot. I will try that.

Comment: I need to get "cricket" and "football" somewhat similar value. If I consider the synsets it will surely return 1. Is there any way to do that? Is vectorizer method will work? or can you please give me any suggessions/reference to study?

Comment: Do you want to compare sentences or words??

Comment: Actually Sentences. I take word by word to simplify it

Comment: Using any of the recent lm models would work. Easiest to use is Google's USE encoder. I posted a link in my answer itself.

Comment: This method also ensures that you get similar representation for words like cricket and football

Comment: You'll need token level or sentence embeddings. Try any of the recent language models. See [this](https://github.com/amansrivastava17/embedding-as-service) for a collated list of models to use.

Answer (score 1):

Semantic Similarity is a bit tricky this way, since even if you use context counts (which would be n-grams > 5) you cannot cope with antonyms (e.g. black and white) well enough. Before using different methods, you could try using a shallow parser or dependency parser for extracting subject-verb or subject-verb-object relations (e.g. ), which you can use as dimensions. If this does not give you the expected similarity (or values adequate for your application), use word embeddings trained on really large data.